# What am I doing wrong in calculating square of iota?

Tags: complex-numbers

Please point out what is wrong with this calculation:

$i^2= (i) (i) $

$=\sqrt{-1} \sqrt{-1} $

$= (-1)^{1/2} (-1)^{1/2} $

$=((-1)(-1))^{1/2}$

$=1^{1/2}$

$=1$

Comment: It was a typo which has been corrected. Please look at the rest of the calculation

Comment: $(-1)^{1/2} (-1)^{1/2} \neq ((-1)(-1))^{1/2}$.  This only works for positive real numbers.

Comment: Beware that $i$ is not iota. $\iota$ is iota.

Comment: This was asked a billion times here. In the complex $a^b a^c=a^{b+c}$ is not always true.

Comment: Never forget that most complex numbers have **two** square roots. $i$ is a square root of $-1$ and so $i^2$ is a square root of $1$, but maybe not the one you want it to be.

Comment: Thanks everyone

Comment: The imaginary number $i$ is "defined" by the relation $i^2=-1,$ where $i$ is a conventional symbol and $-1$ a real number. You cannot assume that $i$ and the complex numbers automatically inherit the properties of the reals. You just found a counterexample.

Comment: @AnginaSeng: positive real numbers also have two square roots, but we define the square root *function* which selects the positive root. A square root *function* can also be defined on the complex.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to this ambiguity the definition of separation of root is given as:

$$ \sqrt{ab}  =\sqrt{a} \sqrt{b}$$

Only if, a > 0 & b > 0.

For example:

$ \sqrt{3.5}$

=$ \sqrt{(-3).(-5)}$

=$ \sqrt{(-3)}.\sqrt{(-5)}$

=$ \sqrt{(3)}i.\sqrt{(5)}i$

=$ \sqrt{(3)}.\sqrt{(5)}i.i$

=$ (-1)\sqrt{(3)}.\sqrt{(5)}$

=$(-1)\sqrt{3.5}$

Thus x = -x, which is wrong. Therefore separation of a root power is not defined for negative numbers.

Comment: when you write $\sqrt{-3}$ as $\sqrt{3}  i$, are you not violating the rule that separation of root power is not defined for negative numbers ?